# smbcacls fails with NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME while smbclient connects

Tags: networking, samba, connection

smbclient works fine:

```
$ smbclient //server1/share1/ -E -W AA -U username%password
Domain=[AA] OS=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1]
smb: \> exit
```

But when I try connecting with smbcacls, it fails with `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`:

```
$ smbcacls //server1/share1/ file1 -U "AA\username%password"
failed tcon_X with NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
cli_full_connection failed! (NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)
```

## Notes:

```
$ smbcacls --version
Version 3.6.23-51.el6
$ uname -a
Linux server2 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 10 11:10:31 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is due to the trailing / in share name. Correct command would be

```
$ smbcacls //server1/share1/ file1 -U "AA\username%password"
```